# How to remove top margin in Latex Beamer

Tags: beamer, margins, titles

I'm playing around with Beamer themes and currently designing a custom title page. However, I can not figure out where the margin between the top of the frame and the top of the text comes from.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
                                                  
\begin{frame}[t,plain]
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is additional space between *Test* and the top of the frame. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\beamer@frametopskip` is normally set to `.2cm plus .5\paperheight` for top aligned frames. You can change it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% top
  \beamer@frametopskip=0cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
                                                  
\begin{frame}[t,plain]
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(using a different background colour for the image so one can see more clearly where the frame stops)